# How do adhesive and cohesive forces affect surface tension?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

Surface tension appears at the interface of two immiscible fluids if the cohesive force of attraction is more than adhesive force. What will be the physical effect if the *adhesive* force is more than *cohesive* force?

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent on the terminology you use (which is why I'm a bit reluctant to write out a full length answer), but the way I understood the question, sounds like your fluids would be miscible (should their mutual attraction be stronger than the cohesive forces), and thus there would also be no surface tension (or no surface to have the tension acting on in the first place).

Comment: I'm likewise unclear on your terminology. Are you saying cohesive forces are oriented parallel to the interface and adhesive forces are perpendicular to the interface?

Comment: @tpg2114 The way I read it (just to clarify my "answer") was that the adhesive force would be the interaction between molecules of types A and B, and cohesion that between A and A (and B and B). Phase separation (immiscibility) should then only be possible if the cohesive forces are stronger than the adhesive ones (there will also be a temperature dependence of course as anything should be miscible in high enough temperatures)

Comment: @amlrg I think the differences in interpretation is a good reason to close it as unclear until the OP clarifies the intention.